# jquery shows hidden div only a few milliseconds

Tags: jquery, html, css

The div nav--contentoverlay and div test only show a few milliseconds and then disappear.How do they show until the next click on one of both?

```js
$(function() {

    $(".js--toggle").click(function() {

/* this functions ($(".test … and $("body … don't work as expected */

        $(".test,.nav--contentoverlay").addClass("js--transition__open");
        $("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
        });
        $(".test,.nav--contentoverlay").click(function() {
            $(".test,.nav--contentoverlay").removeClass("js--transition__open");
            $("body").css("overflow", "auto");
        });

    });
```

```css
.test {
        width: 320px;
        height: 480px;
        background: white;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin: -240px 0 0 -160px;
        border: 1px solid #666;
        z-index: 999;
        visibility: hidden
    }

    .nav--contentoverlay {
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1;
        bottom: 0;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        background: black;
        opacity: 0.4!important;
        z-index: 7;
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    .js--transition__open {
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
        transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">


<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="page">
        <div class="contentholder">
            <nav class="nav--global">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="" class="js--toggle"  title="">test</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>

    <nav class="nav--contentoverlay"></nav>
    <div class="test">Test</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.js--toggle` is a link, so the page is following the link (refreshing the page) when you click on it. You need to disable the default action of the link by passing the event to your function in the click handler and using `preventDefault()`

```js
$(function() {
  $(".js--toggle").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    /* this functions ($(".test … and $("body … don't work as expected */
    $(".test,.nav--contentoverlay").addClass("js--transition__open");
    $("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
  });
  $(".test,.nav--contentoverlay").click(function() {
    $(".test,.nav--contentoverlay").removeClass("js--transition__open");
    $("body").css("overflow", "auto");
    console.log('closed');
  });
});
```

```css
.test {
  width: 320px;
  height: 480px;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -240px 0 0 -160px;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  z-index: 999;
  visibility: hidden
}

.nav--contentoverlay {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.4!important;
  z-index: 7;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.js--transition__open {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">


<head>
  <title>test</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="page">
    <div class="contentholder">
      <nav class="nav--global">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="" class="js--toggle" title="">test</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>

  <nav class="nav--contentoverlay"></nav>
  <div class="test">Test</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That works fine. I am a fool not to notice this. Thank you very much!